# jQuery drag-and-drop issue without jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to do drag-and-drop without using jQuery UI. (200kb is too much to load)

I have two problems:

1. I am not sure how to snap the dragged element to a certain element.
   I know in jQuery UI I can just provide an option like 'snap' but not sure how to do this in plain jQuery.
2. Where can I change the cursor to a pointer icon when I drag the element?

I have the following code:

```
var dragging =null;

obj = $('table td');

$(obj).click(function(e){
    if(dragging){
        dragging = null;
    }
    else{
        dragging = $(e.target);
    }
})

$(document.body).mousemove(function(e){
    var el_w = $(obj).width();
    var el_h = $(obj).height();
    if (dragging) {
        dragging.offset({
            top : e.pageY-el_h/2,
            left : e.pageX-el_w/2
        })
    }
})
```

I have searched Google but almost all of the results suggest jQuery UI... :(

Comment: I hate to say "just use jQuery UI", but bear in mind that if you use a popular CDN there is a possibility that the users have a cached version already from another site. If that's not acceptable, a .min.js version of UI just covering drag and drop is only 37KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom Build

You can download a custom version of jQuery UI.  Follow this link, go to the bottom, and click Download.

#### [draggable only](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&themeParams=none&components=1110100000000000000000000000000000)

The size is **32kb**.  Modern web servers `gzip` the file, which would result in **8.66kb** in transfer.  It can also be combined with other files to reduce the number of network requests.

### Alternative

The amazing Chris Coyer wrote a small plugin that mimics `$.draggable` from jQuery UI.

*Note*: You would have to modify his code to get it to do any kind of snapping, etc.

#### [Draggable without jQuery UI](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/)

If minified with the Closure Compiler, you the file size is **0.769kb** or **0.353kb** gzipped.

<sub>All statistics derived from this [online Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)</sub>